# Не запустить процедуру с параметрами, заданную в базе

Tags: java, jdbc

не получается запустить процедуру бд из java приложения, когда задаю параметры не по номерам столбцов, а по имени столбца.

Часть кода, которая вызывает процедуру:

```
CallableStatement cstmt;
    cstmt = connection.prepareCall("{call SET_CLIENT_ADD (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)}");
    cstmt.setString("FIRSTNAME", client.getFirstName());
    cstmt.setString("LASTNAME", client.getLastName());
    cstmt.setString("MIDNAME", client.getMidName());
    cstmt.setString("PHONE", client.getPhone());
    cstmt.setDate("BDATE", new Date(client.getBirthDate().getTime()));
    cstmt.registerOutParameter(1, Types.INTEGER);
    cstmt.registerOutParameter(2, Types.INTEGER);
    cstmt.registerOutParameter(3, Types.VARCHAR);
    cstmt.execute();
    cstmt.close();
```

Ошибка (возникает на 3ей строке):

```
Exception in thread "main" org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBDriverNotCapableException: Setting parameters by name is not supported
at org.firebirdsql.jdbc.AbstractCallableStatement.setString(AbstractCallableStatement.java:1146)
at JDBCStuff.Services.ClientService.saveClient(ClientService.java:37)
at Main.Main.main(Main.java:23)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Первая ошибка:**

У вас пять входных параметров и три выходных.
В запросе перечислено только 5.

**Вторая ошибка:**

Если к параметрам обращаетесь по именам, то эти имена должны быть указаны в запросе:

```
CallableStatement cstmt;
cstmt = connection.prepareCall("{call SET_CLIENT_ADD (:FIRSTNAME, :LASTNAME, :MIDNAME, :PHONE, :BDATE, :out1, :out2, :out3)}");
cstmt.setString("FIRSTNAME", client.getFirstName());
cstmt.setString("LASTNAME", client.getLastName());
cstmt.setString("MIDNAME", client.getMidName());
cstmt.setString("PHONE", client.getPhone());
cstmt.setDate("BDATE", new Date(client.getBirthDate().getTime()));
cstmt.registerOutParameter("out1", Types.INTEGER);
cstmt.registerOutParameter("out2", Types.INTEGER);
cstmt.registerOutParameter("out3", Types.VARCHAR);
cstmt.execute();
cstmt.close();
```

Если именованные параметры не поддерживаются то придется писать так:

```
CallableStatement cstmt;
cstmt = connection.prepareCall("{call SET_CLIENT_ADD (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)}");
cstmt.setString(1, client.getFirstName());
cstmt.setString(2, client.getLastName());
cstmt.setString(3, client.getMidName());
cstmt.setString(4, client.getPhone());
cstmt.setDate(5, new Date(client.getBirthDate().getTime()));
cstmt.registerOutParameter(6, Types.INTEGER);
cstmt.registerOutParameter(7, Types.INTEGER);
cstmt.registerOutParameter(8, Types.VARCHAR);
cstmt.execute();
cstmt.close();
```

Comment: Кол-во параметров верно указано, а от передачи параметров по индексам столбцов я как раз таки отошел, с индексами, конечно, всё работает, но это неправильно... Повторюсь, что ошибка возникает в 3ей строке, когда пытаюсь добавить входной параметр, к выполнению запроса ошибка не относится

Comment: У вас 5 знаков вопроса. А параметров 8.

Comment: Повторяю ещё раз, к выполнению запроса данная ошибка не относится. У меня проблема возникает на моменте добавления входного параметра

Comment: Вы пишете сначала, что количество параметров указано верно. Я объясняю почему не верно. В ответе все написано: попробуйте запустить первый вариант, но вероятно именованные параметры у вас совсем не поддерживаются.

Comment: Видимо, вы не понимаете вопрос и не совсем разбираетесь. Повторю в 3ий раз, что ошибка не в кол-ве параметров, тем более, как я писал в вопросе, до этого программа работала, только отличие было в том, что вместо названия столбцов я указывал их индексы при добавление параметров. Спасибо за ваш ответ, но не стоит дальше развивать его, ибо он не совсем относится к вопросу.

Comment: Я ответил ровно на тот вопрос который вы задали. Вы проверили первый пример, он у вас заработал? Если нет, то именованные параметры у вас не поддерживаются. "Setting parameters by name is not supported".

Answer (score -1):

Решил вопрос сам, просто сделав класс, который смотрит запрос, а потом парсит название столбца, которое я добавляю, в индекс этого столбца.

```
NamedParamStatement statement = new NamedParamStatement(connection, "{call SET_CLIENT_ADD (:LASTNAME, :FIRSTNAME, :MIDNAME, :PHONE, :BDATE)}");
    statement.setString("FIRSTNAME", client.getFirstName());
    statement.setString("LASTNAME", client.getLastName());
    statement.setString("MIDNAME", client.getMidName());
    statement.setString("PHONE", client.getPhone());
    statement.setDate("BDATE", new Date(client.getBirthDate().getTime()));
    statement.execute();
```

.

```
public class NamedParamStatement {  
private final PreparedStatement statement;

private Map<String, int[]> indexMap;

public NamedParamStatement(Connection connection, String query) throws SQLException {
    String parsedQuery = parse(query);
    statement = connection.prepareStatement(parsedQuery);
}

final String parse(String query) {
    // I was originally using regular expressions, but they didn't work well for ignoring
    // parameter-like strings inside quotes.
    int length = query.length();
    StringBuffer parsedQuery = new StringBuffer(length);
    boolean inSingleQuote = false;
    boolean inDoubleQuote = false;
    int index = 1;
    HashMap<String, List<Integer>> indexes = new HashMap<String, List<Integer>>(10);

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        char c = query.charAt(i);
        if (inSingleQuote) {
            if (c == '\'') {
                inSingleQuote = false;
            }
        } else if (inDoubleQuote) {
            if (c == '"') {
                inDoubleQuote = false;
            }
        } else {
            if (c == '\'') {
                inSingleQuote = true;
            } else if (c == '"') {
                inDoubleQuote = true;
            } else if (c == ':' && i + 1 < length && Character.isJavaIdentifierStart(query.charAt(i + 1))) {
                int j = i + 2;
                while (j < length && Character.isJavaIdentifierPart(query.charAt(j))) {
                    j++;
                }
                String name = query.substring(i + 1, j);
                c = '?'; // replace the parameter with a question mark
                i += name.length(); // skip past the end if the parameter

                List<Integer> indexList = indexes.get(name);
                if (indexList == null) {
                    indexList = new LinkedList<Integer>();
                    indexes.put(name, indexList);
                }
                indexList.add(Integer.valueOf(index));

                index++;
            }
        }
        parsedQuery.append(c);
    }

    indexMap = new HashMap<String, int[]>(indexes.size());
    // replace the lists of Integer objects with arrays of ints
    for (Map.Entry<String, List<Integer>> entry : indexes.entrySet()) {
        List<Integer> list = entry.getValue();
        int[] intIndexes = new int[list.size()];
        int i = 0;
        for (Integer x : list) {
            intIndexes[i++] = x.intValue();
        }
        indexMap.put(entry.getKey(), intIndexes);
    }

    return parsedQuery.toString();
}

private int[] getIndexes(String name) {
    int[] indexes = indexMap.get(name);
    if (indexes == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Parameter not found: " + name);
    }
    return indexes;
}

public void setObject(String name, Object value) throws SQLException {
    int[] indexes = getIndexes(name);
    for (int i = 0; i < indexes.length; i++) {
        statement.setObject(indexes[i], value);
    }
}

public void setString(String name, String value) throws SQLException {
    int[] indexes = getIndexes(name);
    for (int i = 0; i < indexes.length; i++) {
        statement.setString(indexes[i], value);
    }
}

public void setInt(String name, int value) throws SQLException {
    int[] indexes = getIndexes(name);
    for (int i = 0; i < indexes.length; i++) {
        statement.setInt(indexes[i], value);
    }
}

public void setLong(String name, long value) throws SQLException {
    int[] indexes = getIndexes(name);
    for (int i = 0; i < indexes.length; i++) {
        statement.setLong(indexes[i], value);
    }
}

public void setTimestamp(String name, Timestamp value) throws SQLException {
    int[] indexes = getIndexes(name);
    for (int i = 0; i < indexes.length; i++) {
        statement.setTimestamp(indexes[i], value);
    }
}

public void setDate(String name, java.sql.Date value) throws SQLException {
    int[] indexes = getIndexes(name);
    for (int i = 0; i < indexes.length; i++) {
        statement.setDate(indexes[i], value);
    }
}

public void setDate(String name, java.sql.Date value, Calendar cal) throws SQLException {
    int[] indexes = getIndexes(name);
    for (int i = 0; i < indexes.length; i++) {
        statement.setDate(indexes[i], value, cal);
    }
}

public PreparedStatement getStatement() {
    return statement;
}

public boolean execute() throws SQLException {
    return statement.execute();
}

public ResultSet executeQuery() throws SQLException {
    return statement.executeQuery();
}

public int executeUpdate() throws SQLException {
    return statement.executeUpdate();
}

public void close() throws SQLException {
    statement.close();
}

public void addBatch() throws SQLException {
    statement.addBatch();
}

public int[] executeBatch() throws SQLException {
    return statement.executeBatch();
}
```

}

Comment: В своем ответе я вам указал, что "эти имена должны быть указаны в запросе". Вы сделали то же самое, и еще отказались от выходных параметров!

Comment: Выходные параметры остались, они достаются, как ResultSet. Но вы до сих пор не поняли сути проблемы. Простое добавление названий полей в запрос не давало эффекта. А дизлайкая мой ответ вы только ещё раз показываете, что пытаетесь ответить на вопрос и доказать свою точку зрения, при этом совершенно не разбираясь в данной теме.

Comment: Решение полезное, но вопрос задан другой.